# Kendo-Knockout: use knockout view model with kendo datasource

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

I am doing some experiments with Kendo, Knockout and kendo-knockoutjs libraries. I want to use knockout view model with kendo datasource and to bind it to the kendo grid widget.

In Kendo:

html:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="reportGrid" data-bind="source: gridDataSource"></div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var billingReportViewModel = kendo.observable({
    gridDataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({data:[{name:"Apple", color:"green"},{name:"Banana", color:"yellow"}]})
});

$("#reportGrid").kendoGrid();

kendo.bind($("#main"), billingReportViewModel);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zeQMT/71/

What I want to accomplish:

The html is the same as the example above.

javascript:

```
var billingReportViewModel = ko.observable({
    gridDataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({data:[{name:"Apple", color:"green"},{name:"Banana", color:"yellow"}]})
});

$("#reportGrid").kendoGrid();


ko.applyBindings(billingReportViewModel);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zeQMT/72/

Obviuosly, this will not work because knockoutjs does not have `source` binding. Is it possible to create custom binding named `source` so that the current example will work? Any help with working code will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I started a branch quite a while ago to handle passing in a kendo.data.DataSource reference directly, but never completed the fix: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-kendo/issues/6

If there is interest, then I could try to get this one resolved.

Otherwise, you can define the dataSource in the binding (or pass in an object).  Like:

```
var billingReportViewModel = ko.observable({
    gridDataSource: {data:[{name:"Apple", color:"green"},{name:"Banana", color:"yellow"}]}
});
```

Then, bind like:

```
<div id="reportGrid" data-bind="kendoGrid: { data: undefined, dataSource: gridDataSource }"></div>
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/6SEzp/

Comment: I would love for this to be added. Definition of the Datasource scheme is pretty important when it comes to parsing numbers (e.g. currency, significant digits) and dates! :-)

Comment: How can I get a knockoutjs observableArray of the items that re currently in the kendoui DataSource?  As the datasource pages and filters and sorts, the knockout observableArray would change...

Comment: @RPNiemeyer was this ever resolved? I can't seem to get the example above to work. Setting data to undefined and dataSource to a property on the viewModel does nothing for me.

Comment: @Jacques - a fix was made to accept a dataSource directly like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/fq4cx1gq/. Hope that helps!

Comment: @RPNiemeyer is there a release history somewhere highlighting this fix and for which version? 
I'm having a lot of problems getting this integration between kendo and KO to work specifically with the Grid.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer I found the release history on GH, the only reference to dataSource is in v0.7 and v0.9.3 but the latter of the two seems to be related to the TreeView only? 
Also, the examples on the Knockout-Kendo site show examples of how settings can be specified for the Grid using declarative syntax in HTML but when I add sortable or filterable it definitely doesn't work. However pageable does? 
https://jsfiddle.net/jacquesvanderhoven/htq9z5vp/2/ this is a fiddle where I've added sortable which is not working.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer just realised that it's the same fiddle where I actually get the dataSource binding to work, so it definitely works. But, sortable, filterable etc doesn't work. And, what about if you want to specify more details for the dataSource object like sort, schema, etc.?