# Kendo Knockout: loading treeView with kendo.data.dataSource

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

Currently kendo-knockout library does not support passing kendo.data.dataSource into bindings. I was able to load the treeView with kendo data source using the widget reference sample in the update of my post here: [Kendo-Knockout: use knockout view model with kendo datasource to populate kendoTreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331804/kendo-knockout-use-knockout-view-model-with-kendo-datasource-to-populate-kendot). But was unable to add and remove items to it as well as some other issues.
I am writing this question based on a comment by RP Niemeyer in github:

https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-kendo/issues/6

saying that this should be possible if I pass something like `data: false, dataSource: yourDataSource` and this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/s5G5k/

Following this example I tried to make an implementation of the treeView:

http://jsfiddle.net/s5G5k/6/

but I am getting an error: `Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined`

So my question here is can this work and can I then add/remove objects to the dataSource and see the view updates accordingly? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like I need to revisit being able to pass a dataSource in directly. Sorry, did not get a chance to dig into this one or the other tree view question that you have yet.

Comment: I see. Do You plan to implement this functionality shortly? I am thinking of recreating the tree view in the dom every time a node has been added or deleted for now. Or is there any workaround I can use ?And later refactor this part when your implementation is ready. Thanks.

Comment: Recreating it is probably the best option for now. You could possibly wrap it in a `with` and update the value of the `with` when you want it rebound.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood correctly the 'with' binding scenario. I made this: http://jsfiddle.net/6SEzp/108/ but it still does not update the view. Can You please update the fiddle with your idea if possible?

Comment: Maybe more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/6VZxB/

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. Please post your solution to a separate post so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really need to revisit adding the ability to pass a dataSource directly into the widgets.

One solution for now is to wrap your treeview in a "with" binding and have it get re-rendered when you add/remove items.

Maybe like:

```
<div data-bind="with: treeView">
    <div id="reportGrid" data-bind="kendoTreeView: { dataSource: treeViewDataSource }"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/6VZxB/